# Rake Default namespace runs tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, minitest, rake-test

I'm attempting to run some tests on my rails application, and they're working, which is great. However, I'm noticing that when I just run `rake` it defaults to running my tests. If anybody has run into this before and can shed some light on why this is happening, I'd appreciate it.

I'm using

- rails 4.1.0
- ruby 2.0.0
- factory girl rails
- minitest rails
- minitest rails capybara
- database cleaner

`Rakefile`

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

Pinteresting::Application.load_tasks

namespace :test do
  task :run do
    ENV["RACK_ENV"] = "test"
    $LOAD_PATH.unshift("lib", "spec")
    if ARGV[1]
      require_relative ARGV[1]
    else
      Dir.glob("./spec/**/*_spec.rb").each { |file| require file }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: the default `rake task` in rails is `test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default rake task is defined in [rails/railties/Rakefile](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/Rakefile#L4), and it runs all unit tests by default.

[image]